Cannot resolve symbol 'MoreObjects'
I have this old legacy code:
dependency com.google.guava:guava:15.0
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @JoinColumn(
    name = "recipient_profile")
    private Profile recipientProfile;
    ....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "standalone_credit")
public class StandaloneCredit {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private UUID id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipient_profile_internal_id")
    private Profile recipientBusinessProfile;
    ....
}

import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;
StandaloneCredit credit;

Profile recipientProfile =
        MoreObjects.firstNonNull(credit.getRecipientProfile(), credit.getRecipientBusinessProfile());

com.google.guava:guava:15.0 is a dependency from implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:2.2.10.RELEASE'
How I can replace MoreObjects without breaking the code logic with core Java code implementation?

What exactly are you asking? Are you asking what MoreObjects.firstNonNull does? Do you know, and you're asking how to do that in plain Java?

Sorry. Updated code.

I don't think you've answered @tgdavies' question.

I mean how I can replace the code from com.google.common.base.MoreObjects with core Java code while keeping the same code functionality?

MoreObjects.firstNonNull can be directly replaced by Objects.requireNonNullElse:
Profile recipientProfile = Objects.requireNonNullElse(
        credit.getRecipientProfile(), credit.getRecipientBusinessProfile());

Recent versions of the Guava Javadocs have specific instructions to make this replacement, in fact:

Java 9 users: use java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse(first, second) instead.

To add a little more context, the Guava MoreObjects.firstNonNull method predates Java 9 when Objects.requireNonNullElse was added to Java.  The expectation is that users using Guava on newer versions of Java should migrate to the built-in Java method.
Javadocs
Reviewing the Javadocs of the two methods shows that they are expected to behave identically to each other.
MoreObjects.firstNonNull

public static <T> T firstNonNull​(@CheckForNull T first, @CheckForNull T second)
Returns the first of two given parameters that is not null, if either is, or otherwise throws a NullPointerException.
[…]
Throws:
NullPointerException - if both first and second are null

Objects.requireNonNullElse

public static <T> T requireNonNullElse(T obj, T defaultObj)
Returns the first argument if it is non-null and otherwise the second argument if it is non-null.
[…]
Throws:
NullPointerException - if both obj is null and defaultObj is null


For this specific use case, the dependency can be eliminated by adding this pure Java method to your class.
public static Profile firstNonNull(Profile p1, Profile p2) {
    if(p1 != null)
        return p1;
    else if(p2 != null)
        return p2;
    else
        throw new NullPointerException("Both profiles are null.");
}

Then the calling code can be updated like so:
Profile recipientProfile = firstNonNull(credit.getRecipientProfile(), credit.getRecipientBusinessProfile());

A general solution using generics could also be written, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

The generics solution is a very straightforward change of the method signature line: public static <T> T firstNonNull(T p1, T p2) {
